# Disable/Enable NSButton if NSTextfield is empty or not

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsbutton

I´m newbie with cocoa. I have a button and a textField in my app. I want the button disabled when the textfield is empty and enabled when the user type something.

Any point to start? Any "magic" binding in Interface Builder?

Thanks

[EDITED]

I´ve tried to set the appDelegate as the NSTextfield´s delegate and added this method (myTextfield and myButton are IBOutlets):

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if ([[myTextField stringValue]length]>0) {
        [myButton setEnabled: YES];
    }
    else {
        [myButton setEnabled: NO];
    }
}
```

But nothing happens...

Comment: Could you try the same thing with [myTextField.text isEqualToString: @""] in your condition instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I´ve tried to set the appDelegate as the NSTextfield´s delegate and added this method (myTextfield and myButton are IBOutlets):
>
> ```
> - (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
> {
>     if ([[myTextField stringValue]length]>0) {
>         [myButton setEnabled: YES];
>     }
>     else {
>         [myButton setEnabled: NO];
>     }
> }
> ```

That's the hard way, but it should work just fine. Either you haven't hooked up the text field's `delegate` outlet to this object, you haven't hooked up the `myTextField` outlet to the text field, or you haven't hooked up the `myButton` outlet to the button.

The other way would be to give the controller a property exposing the string value, bind the text field's `value` binding to this `stringValue` property, and bind the button's `enabled` binding to the controller's `stringValue.length`.

You could also give the controller two properties, one having a Boolean value, and set that one up as dependent upon the string property, and bind the button to that. That's a cleaner and possibly more robust solution, though it is more work.

Comment: Hello Peter. After some months I need to solve this again with another app. Now that my knowledge about bindings (and cocoa) is better, I´ve tried your solution and it works perfect. And just with a property and two bindings! (Much cleaner than using delegate methods, observers and outlets...) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution using bindings.

Below I setup a NSTextField that is bound to the file owner's "text" property. "text" is a NSString. **I was caught by "Continuously Updates Value".** Thinking my solution didn't work but really it wasn't updating as the user typed, and only when the textfield lost focus.

[image: Binding the NSTextField to the file's owner NSString text property]

And now setting up bindings on the button, simply set its enabled state to the length of the file owner's text property.

[image: Binding the NSButton's enabled state to the text property's length]

Annd, the working product.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the UI has change a little in Xcode 8. I created a property `dynamic var text : NSString` and was able to bind 'self.text` to the text field, but I couldn't get the second part working. What do you put for `Controller key`?

Answer (score 4):

If you use controlTextDidChange instead of textDidChange, you can get rid of the notification stuff and just rely on being the NSTextField's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter. What I missed (in  my hard way version) is this piece of code in the awakeFromNib in the appDelegate:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification object:myTextField];
```

It works perfect. Now I´m trying the easy way, but I´m afraid I´m not still good enough with the bindings.

To bind the property

```
@property (retain) IBOutlet NSString *aStringValue;
```

with the textfield´s value, what I have to use in IB for "Bind to:", "Controller Key" and "Model Key Path"?