# Cocoa notification, how to observe for event?

Tags: cocoa, events, user-interface

I have a TextField in my Cocoa application. This TextField will be sometimes filled and sometimes empty.

I want it so that when the field is empty a button is disabled. Now I check the field whenever I do some action with Core Data from where the TextField gets its value.

I'd like for it to always be checked for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the user edits the text field and brings up the field editor then you can use the following.

You can implemented the [NSTextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol (which is really just the [NSControlTextEditing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSControlTextEditingDelegate) protocol). For example, in a controller or a delegate object implement the `control:textShouldEndEditing:` method and use this to check the values of the new string. If the string is empty then disable the button.

```
// In a control object which has a reference to the NSTextField and the NSButton
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor {
    if ([fieldEditor.string isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {
        [self.button setEnabled:NO];
        return YES;
    }

    [self.button setEnabled:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

---

**Update:** Sorry missed that bit about CodeData. In this case you should follow the instructions here, [Disable/Enable NSButton if NSTextfield is empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726201/disable-enable-nsbutton-if-nstextfield-is-empty-or-not),

> The other way would be to give the controller a property exposing the
>   string `value`, bind the text field's value binding to this `stringValue`
>   property, and bind the button's `enabled` binding to the controller's
>   `stringValue.length`.